# Calculate sum of unique tag values

Tags: grafana, influxdb

sometimes it appears that one have to calculate SUM of unique TAG values in InfluxDB. How to do it?

For example I have multiple users who downloads software. Now I want to extract how many unique users downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Following query was tested in Grafana to calculate unique users and also consider time filter applied to the database.

To do this we need to apply subquery first to calculate mean values, this basically will result a table with value 1 associated for each user:

```
SELECT mean("count") FROM "autogen"."downloads" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "username"
```

Here *count* is an integer value that is equal to 1 for each time user downloads the software.

After we can calculate sum of these mean values, yes, this is not cheap if you have a huge database, but still is a working solution:

```
SELECT SUM(mean) FROM (
    SELECT mean("count") FROM "autogen"."downloads" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "username"
)
```

Please go ahead and propose best performing/more native solution, this will be nice to apply for larger DBs

Comment: Why you can't use tag cardinality query? Your question doesn't include time filtering, so tag cardinality will be the best option. IMHO you need to use `SELECT COUNT(mean)` instead of `SELECT SUM(mean)` if you want count of unique users.

Comment: @JanGaraj, tried this, this does not work. While if you sum mean, where it is 1 for each user, then you get number of unique users